# Testing whether a Sample is from a known Population

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I was wondering if I could ask a question to the Stats Folk.

Consider a random variable $Y$ with a given $E[Y]$ and $V[Y]$ that is known.

Now consider that a set of sample data is collected $X$, it itself has it's own sample $E[X]$ and $V[X]$ and sample size $n$.

My question, is there a statistical test to determine whether $X$ is a true sample of $Y$? 
Or some sort of assessment of this?

We very often see analysis that allows for a sample to be analysed under the assumption it's from a certain population, but I've been unable to find any that test where $X \subseteq Y$.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking here, but I wonder whether you are aware that there is a stackexchange site for statistics questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know not only the mean and variance but also the true theoretical distribution of Y and the empirical distribution of X, you can apply [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). This test basically just tests *how close* are these two distributions to each other.

Comment: Yes, I did mean Variance. Thank you for the reference. Do you know of any others?

From what I've read, this mainly tests whether a sample $X$ is of the same type as $Y$, rather than $X$ being a true sample of $Y$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " being a true sample of ". Especially what "true" sample means?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been cleared in my details. Perhaps an example would be better. Consider I made three different types of chocolate $C_1, C_2, C_3$ with respective calorie averages and variances $E[C_i]$, $V[C_i]$. Now, lets say that I receive a box of chocolates ($S$) that are all of the same type, but without labels. It has an average and variance of $E[S]$, $V[S]$. How could I determine or forecast whether the sample of chocolates $S$ is $C_1, C_2$, or $C_3$?

Answer (score 0):

Here are summary statistics for three samples, each of size $n = 500,$ sampled from three different distributions.

```
summary(a); sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-2.3961  0.3281  0.9793  1.0018  1.6610  4.1959 
[1] 1.034814     # Std Devn: a
summary(b); sd(b)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.001137 0.315328 0.747986 0.993007 1.410341 6.023057 
[1] 0.9158659    # Std Devn: b
summary(c); sd(c)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.003384 0.518120 1.037977 1.009476 1.490161 1.997519 
[1] 0.5622965    # Std Devn: c
```

Now I have another sample `x` of size 200, and I wonder
if it might have come from the same distribution of one of `a`, `b`, or `c`.

```
summary(x);  sd(x)
   Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.001541 0.311374 0.771930 1.120292 1.642017 5.614681 
[1] 1.089492   # Std devn x
```

There are some similarities among the samples: all four
have means near 1. Samples `b`, `c`, and `x` take
only positive values. Samples `b` and `x` have
standard deviations near 1. So just from the usual
descriptive statistics, `x` seems similar to `b`, but not especially similar to `a` or `b`.

Trying to match histograms of various samples of
intermediate sizes often does not help solve puzzles
like this, because the binning can produce misleading effects.

However, comparing empirical CDFs can sometimes be
more fruitful. To make the ECDF of a sample: sort observations in order, and make a stairstep function that increases by $1/n$ at each sorted observation (jumps of $2/n$ or $3/n$, etc. in case there are ties).
So the ECDF starts at 0 at the left edge of the graph and reaches 1 at the right edge. (The ECDF of a sufficiently large sample approximates the CDF of the
distribution from which it was sampled.)

Here are ECDFs of samples `a`, `b`, and `c`. The 
ECDF of sample `x` is superimposed on the each of these ECDFs to see if there are any likely matches.

[image]

Pretty clearly `x` does not match `a` or `c`, but it
seem a possible match to `b`.

As suggested by @Andrew (+1), we do Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests for formal tests of matches. A P-value above 0.05 is an indication of a possible match; P-values below 0.05 pretty clearly indicate no match. Below I use `$`-notation to show only the P-values, and not other details of the K-S tests.

```
ks.test(a,x)$p.val   
[1] 0.001911254      # no match
ks.test(b,x)$p.val
[1] 0.5045157        # possible match
ks.test(c,x)$p.val
[1] 0.0003169227     # no match
```

In practice, with data from real-world situations, here is no way to know for sure that two samples
come from exactly the same population, but the K-S test is
a good way of quantifying the agreement of ECDFs,
which is one of the best ways to judge possible matches.

---

*Note:* In this particular example, we *can* know that
samples `b` and `x` came from the same population because the data are *simulated.*

The four samples were simulated in R, using the code
below:

```
set.seed(1234)
a = round(rnorm(500, 1,  1), 6)
b = round(rexp(500, 1), 6)
c = round(runif(500, 0, 2), 6)
x = round(rexp(200, 1), 6)
```